# GIT Clone Failing from Raspberry Pi 3 B+

Tags: linux, git, github, raspberry-pi3

I am trying to run this command from my Raspberry Pi 3B+(connected to my PC via SSH):
sudo git clone https://github.com/lthiery/SPI-Py.git

The result is:
**fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/lthiery/SPI-Py.git/': Failed to connect to github.com port 443: No route to host**

I tried : **ping github.com**, its NOT working either.
But I can ping to google.com and many others successfully.

**I am using my Mobile as Hotspot to connect to both my PC and Raspberry Pi.**
One last thing I can ping github.com from my PC successfully but not from my RaspberryPi.

I am new to this so please be as specific as possible.
Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Since this seems to be a networking related issue, this question may be better asked at https://unix.stackexchange.com or https://superuser.com

Comment: Thanks. Will do that.